# In Extjs ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) is returning false

Tags: java, extjs

I have following code in my js file in extjs

For making of browse button

```
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        labelAlign: 'left',
        width: 800,
        emptyText: 'Select a file',
        fieldLabel: 'File ',
        buttonText: 'Browse',
        fileUpload: true,
        id  : 'BROWSE_BUTTON', name : 'BROWSE_BUTTON'
```

To pass request to Controller

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url     : 'controller/upload',
        method  : 'GET',
        params  : { 
            fileName    : fileName,
            docDesc:     docDesc
            },
             headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                contentType: false,
```

Above code returns `ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)`  false and hence I am not getting from upload.parseRequest(request). Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

File uploads are not performed using normal "Ajax" techniques, that is they are not performed using XMLHttpRequests.
[More information](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection)

There is a tricky method that uses dynamically generated, hidden `<iframe>` which is inserted into the document but removed after the return data has been gathered. [More information](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/ajax-file-uploads-with-the-iframe-method/)

Fortunately, Ext.Ajax uses this technique by its `upload(form, url, params, options)` method.

There is a simple way to upload a file to the server:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        bodyPadding: 5,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'form',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'filefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'File',
                        name: 'file'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Save',
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('window').down('form').getForm();
                    form.submit({
                        url: 'www.domain.com',
                        waitMsg: 'Uploading...'
                    });
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    win.show();
});
```

A form with a file upload field is not submitted using an XMLHttpRequest object—instead the framework creates and submits a temporary hidden `<form>` element whose target is referenced to a temporary hidden `<iframe>`. The request header's Content-Type is set to multipart/form. When the upload is finished and the server has responded, the temporary form and `<iframe>` are removed.

A fake XMLHttpRequest object is then created containing a responseText property (populated from the contents of the `<iframe>`) to ensure that event handlers and callbacks work as if we were submitting the form using AJAX.

Comment: Can you please tell what should be passed in form in my code

Ext.Ajax.upload
({
 url     : 'controller/upload',
 form :  ---------------------------------------------
        method  : 'GET',
        params  : { 
            fileName    : fileName,
            docDesc:     docDesc
            },
             headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
                },
                contentType: false,

Comment: It depends, mostly you handle the button's click in your controller and the handler is received an instance of your button as an argument, with `button.up('form')` you can get the instance of the form.

Comment: xtype : 'button', 
            text : 'Save & Exit',
Thanks Abbas.. I am using above button on click of which I call Ext.Ajax.upload
No when i pass  url     : 'controller/upload',
 form :  Ext.getCmp('BROWSE_BUTTON').up('form')
 
 It gives me Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttribute'

Comment: Well, the information you have provided in your question is insufficient to answer your question completely, please update your question with complete form definition and the controller. it would be better if you could share your code in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Hi Abbas..  Sorry for inconvinience. Sharing complete code will be a challenge for me. But what i can say is . I wrote following code
  Ext.Ajax.upload({
 url  :  'controller/upload'
  method  : 'GET',
   form :  Ext.getCmp('BROWSE_BUTTON').up('form'),
  isUpload : true,
  params  : { 
   fileName : fileName,
   docDesc:     docDesc
   },
    headers : {
           'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
       },
       contentType: false,
  scope : this,

  When I click Save & Exit button above ajax is triggered and I get "Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttribute'"

Comment: But when I use Ext.Ajax.request(...) I do not get above error. Instead I get ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) as false.
  
  I do not have any 'form' in my js.. Can that be a problem. Simple Browse button (given in my question) and Save and Exit button I have

Comment: Of course, the method uses the the form instance to accomplish its job, without a form you can not use the upload method and I have to mention that in ExtJS you should use form because without that you have to write some fragile, rigid and repetitive code.

Comment: Thanks again Abbas. Can you please tell if it is possible for you to give me an example of a form in js file with 2 buttons (Browse and save)

Comment: That will be a great help Abbas

Comment: Abbas Thanks for the code. I have used your code but when I give the url of controller where I want the request to be redirected it gives me bad request 400 error. I am writing following code in url where controller is my java file which contains upload() function
 
 
                text: 'Save',
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('window').down('form').getForm();
                    form.submit({
                        url: 'controller/upload,
                        waitMsg: 'Uploading...'
                    });

Comment: You're welcome, bad request  - sometimes - means that your server expects some information which is not provided. maybe the file-name is incorrect or something. You should check your server's upload functionality with a tool like Fiddler (www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: I checked why I am getting that Bad request. It depends on my url what I write. When I give normal link suppose www.domain.com like you have shown it works. But I want that control should go to my java file that is my controller.
     Is it possible that using this url property we pass control to the java file

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge about java is not sufficient to answer your question. You should put another question which java experts will answer you.